# How to run Java with System.in inputs in php with command-line

Tags: java, php, command-line, system.in

It's weekend and I am beginning a new Project
To make the core part of the Project I need a performance oriented execution of Java **with System.in** (or other, if other, better options are available) with php

I have connected my php with exec and popen with my java class,
but after one execution it starts another java.class doing exactly the same as the one before instead of giving it again to the with System.in waiting java

My php file

```php
    var_dump(exec('"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\xampp\htdocs\programmierzeugs\phpCallsJava\bin\production\java test');

    var_dump(exec('"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\xampp\htdocs\programmierzeugs\phpCallsJava\bin\production\java test hi');
```

and my Java class

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("test123");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
```

output is :

```
string(7) "test123"  
string(7) "test123"
```

through suggestions of @MDuh I changed the program to:

```php
$handle = proc_open('"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\xampp\htdocs\programmierzeugs\phpCallsJava\bin\production\java test',
    [0 => ['pipe', 'r'], 1 => ['pipe', 'w'], 2 => ['pipe', 'r']], $pipes);

if ($err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]))
{
    echo $err;
} else {
    var_dump(fread($pipes[0], 6));
    echo (string) fwrite($pipes[1], 'hi');
    var_dump(fread($pipes[1], 3));
}
```

following problem:
after I read more than 7 chars in (the test string is 'test123'), `fread()` randomly deadlocks me (and sometimes does it not) and `stream_get_cotents()` does it instantly. Fwrite gives me back a false and I'd guess that's why I don't have anything to read in

Comment: Are you trying to catch "test" and "test hi" with Java's scanner? You're passing them as arguments and not as a standard input.

Comment: my file is called test ... the java receives just in the second case a argument.  What do you mean I don't give it in as a standart input? I am pretty much deadlocked in my thoughts, can you please help me?

Comment: So you meant to only spawn 1 instance of "test" and want "hi" to be read in the scanner? You need to use [proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and pipe the php output  and java output accordingly

Comment: ok, I have seen proc_open and I don't see through the command, can you help me a bit?

Comment: @MDuh I am messing up with the pipes: can you help me directing the pipes?